# Algorithm to Solve Genetic Crossover Problem

Tags: c#, algorithm, bioinformatics

I have a list of objects like:

```
class PairingStrand
{
   int startInt; // the start pos
   int endInt;   // the end pos
   int Index;    // the index of pairing
   int Strand;   // Strand is either "5" or "3"
}
```

Each position (integer) can only be affiliated with one object.

An objects with `Strand = 5` is pairing with an object having the same "Index" and `strand = 3`.

The list is ordered by the "startInt" of each object. So the different pairings regions could cross over with one another.

**The "CROSS-OVER" means two regions overlap, but if one region is large enough to completely engulf the other one, it is not considered to be "CROSS-OVER".**

For example...

```
{10~15 : 40~45} (startInt ~ endInt : startInd ~ endInx)
```

is cross-over with

```
{20~30 : 60~70}
```

However,

```
{10~15 : 40~45}
```

is not considered to be cross over with

```
{20~25: 30~35}
```

My question is how to identify **the largest block which does not have any cross-over with any other blocks in the list.** The cross-over is allowed inside the block. (In other words, "Cross-over" is allowed but not required inside block, while it is not allowed between blocks)

Maybe I did not describe the question very clearly. Here is a simple example:

List as below:

```
obj1 (10~20, index 1, strand 5)
obj2 (25~30, index 2, strand 5)
obj3 (31~32, index 4, strand 5)
obj4 (33~34, index 4, strand 3)
obj5 (35~45, index 1, strand 3)
obj6 (50~55, index 2, strand3)
obj7 (60~80, index 3, strand 5)
obj8 (90~110, index 3, strand 3)
```

After process, the function should return a block composed of `(obj1 ~ obj6)`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not knowledgable in such things, but is this a genetic algorithm problem?

Comment: Yes, it is an algorithm to solve a genetic problem.

Comment: genetic algorithms are something else.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what “cross-over” means for you? Because your examples don't make sense to me. At all.

Comment: Do you mean that crossover is **required** inside the block?  Otherwise I don't see why the answer wouldn't always be the full list, since it's the largest block not overlapping anything outside it.

Comment: The cross-over is not required but allowed inside block. However, cross-over is not allowed between blocks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Dictionary<Index, Pairing> openPairings;
List<Index> possibilities;

foreach(pairing)
{
    if(openPairings.ContainsKey(pairing.Index))
    {
        // This is the closing of the pair
        // When there are no other open strands at the time of closing,
        // AND the pairing was in the possibilities list, it could be the largest
        if(possibilities.Contains(pairing.Index))
        {
            // The opening entry: openPairings[pairing.Index]
            // The closing pairing: pairing
            // Do your size check here to find the largest
        }
        openPairings.Remove(pairing.Index);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is the opening of the pair
        // There must be no other open pairings or there will be an overlap OR
        // the outer pairing is larger anyway, as it completely engulfs this pairing
        if(openPairings.IsEmpty)
            possibilities.Add(pairing.Index);
        openPairings.Add(pairing.Index, pairing);
    }
}
```